# GWT: formfactor dependent editor

Tags: gwt

I'm developing a web app for different formfactors. Each has its own client factory to create formfactor dependent views. Everythings works fine so far but I'm stuck when it comes to the Editor Framework.

To make use of the framework I have to declare a marker interface like so:
`interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<User, UserEditor> {}`

Since this happens in my formfactor agnostic activity I want the type `UserEditor` to refer to the actual implementation based on the formfactor, i.e. `UserEditorPhone`, `UserEditorTablet`, `UserEditorYouNameIt`.

To no avail I tried using deferred binding in module.gwt.xml:

```
<replace-with class="com.example.client.desktop.UserEditorDesktop">
    <when-type-is class="com.example.client.view.UserEditor"/>
</replace-with>
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing and how to avoid having a one-to-one-relationship between formfactors and UserEditor-activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want your *formfactor-agnostic activity* to only know about `SimpleBeanEditorDriver<User, ?>`, and move the `Driver` interface into each one of `UserEditorDesktop`, `UserEditorTable` and `UserEditorPhone`.

The activity will then ask a formfact-dependent object (e.g. its view, if you use MVP and the activity is the presenter) for an instance of the editor driver rather than using `GWT.create()` directly.

(I can give code sample if you detail how your code is organized: are you using MVP? is the editor your view? how's it instantiated? etc.)

Comment: Hi Thomas, sounds as easy as promising, thanks! However, tried it that way declaring `private final SimpleBeanEditorDriver<User, ? extends UserEditor> driver;` in the activity, and on calling `driver.initialize(editor)` I keep getting `method initialize(capture#3-of ? extends UserEditor) ... is not applicable for the arguments (UserEditor)` (~same w/out the upper bound). Sounds like weird GWT interna to me: any hint on how to get around this? Indeed I'm using MVP, and the editor acts as the view.

Comment: How about calling `initialize` in the formfactory-dependent object that creates the `SimpleBeanEditorDriver`? `Driver d = GWT.create(Driver.class); d.initialize(editor); return d;`

Comment: Swell! Thanks a lot for helping out!